# SQL Server 2000 merge replication – Undo Reinitialize All subscriptions

Tags: merge, sql-server-2000, replication

We currently have one publisher and four subscribers using merge replication. Due to a change in the schema somebody performed a “Reinitialize All subscriptions” action without checking the “Upload the changes at the subscriber before reinitializing” option.  When the replication agent for the first server was started, the database was cleaned out. (All tables dropped and recreated) And all of the changes since the last successful synchronization were lost. At this point we decided to disable the replication schedule completely. My question is, is there a way to undo the “Reinitialize All subscriptions” action? Preferably, in such a way, that all of the changes at the subscribers aren’t lost.

Thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to restore a backup of the publisher database prior to the reinitialize action. (This was done after creating a separate backup for the current publisher database.) After this we manually re-applied the changes which had been done since the reinitialize action from the database with the reinitialize action in it to the restored backup. (We used Redgate sql data compare). At this point we were able to start the replication process and everything worked as it should. So apparently the snapshot information is completely stored inside the database to which it applies.

A special thanks to Hilary Cotter for pointing this out.